# Doubly Linked List Issues?

Tags: c, list, linked-list, structure

I've created, what I think to be a doubly linked list. The idea is to reverse output of words entered each on a new line, so:

```
Hello\nAll\n.
.\nAll\nHello
```

The idea is to traverse my list until `'\n'` is found, then go in the opposite direction and print that off, go back to where I left, continue traversing until another new line, then go forward again and print etc.

However, my current implementation I can't seem to get to work and I've hit a brick wall, and hints or tips are appreciated!

```
typedef struct L { 
char val;
struct L *next;
struct L *prev;
}List;

List *insertList(char val, List *t1 );
List *createList(void);

int main(void) {
  List *z = createList();
  List *pos = z;
  while (pos != NULL) {
    while ( z->val != '\n' ) {
        if (z == NULL)
            break;
            z = z->next;
            pos = z;
}
    while (z != NULL) {
        printf("%c", z->val);
        z = z->prev;
    }
}
return 0;
}
List *createList(void) {
  List *h = NULL;
  char c;
  do { 
    c =(char)getchar();
    h = insertList(c, h);
  }while(c != '.');
  return h;
 }
List *insertList( char val, List *t1) {
  List *t = calloc(1, sizeof( List ));
  t->prev = NULL;
  t->val = val;
  t->next = t1;
    if (t1 != NULL) {
     t1->prev = t;
  }
return t;
}
```

Comment: Can you change the list structure at all during this operation? It might simplify things a bit if, once you've printed a line, you can free all those nodes and remove them from the list.

Comment: No, I cannot change the structure at all

Comment: Well that's dumb. Not that it's your fault, but the major advantage of linked lists is that you can reorder the elements. (Also, you should add the homework tag if this is homework. We'll still help you, but we don't want to do all the work for you if you're supposed to be learning.)

Comment: @user1048116 Can you clarify what you mean by not allowed to change the structure at all.  Are you allowed to change the functionality of createList or is that not allowed to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

I think your structure needs to be changed and there is no reason to have a double linked list to solve your problem.

your struct should contain

```
struct node {
char *word;
struct node *next;
};
```

Then your main loop should be something like:

```
1) Read character data until delimiter into expandable buffer. Add NULL string terminator.
2) When delimiter is reached create node that points to buffer.
3) Insert NODE at HEAD of list.
4) When '.' is reached print each string starting from head of list.
```

Comment: Sorry, but the task specifies I cannot use Arrays/Strings.

Comment: How about instead then: a linked list where each entry in the list contains a word which is a linked list of characters?

Answer (score 1):

Try these while loops instead [EDITED to note Chris' comment about checking for end of LL]:

```
while (pos != NULL) {
    while (z != NULL) {
        // if you've reached the line feed or the end of the linked list
        if ((z->val == '\n') || (z->next == NULL)) {
            pos = z->next; // store list position just after this char for next time through
            break;
        }
        z = z->next;
    }
    while (z != NULL) {
        printf("%c", z->val);
        z = z->prev;
        // don't print more than just this word!:
        if ((z != NULL) && (z->val == '\n'))
            break;
    }
    // reset z for top inner while loop
    z = pos;
}
```

Basic issue was that z was not reset when the outer while loop wrapped around; second issue was that end of linked list didn't break out of first inner while loop; third issue was second inner while loop didn't check for end of the word it was printing.

You also need to free the linked list at the end or it'll be a memory leak.  You should also check the return value of `calloc()` to be sure it didn't return null.

Comment: Definately progress, although when I enter such like Damien\nHello\n. The output I get it that off .\nHello\n then the program crashes

Comment: You need to handle the beginning of the input, which isn't terminated by a `'\n'` character, but still needs to be printed. But this is close.

Comment: Would that be something I would need to implement in a seperate loop, or something I could integrate into the above

Comment: Looking at your linked list creation, won't all the characters be inserted in reverse order?

Also, can you debug the program to locate the crash point?

Also note you're not freeing the linked list when main() finishes which is a memory leak.  Oh, and not checking the return of calloc() that may fail if the OS runs out of memory.

Comment: Chris, any little hints possible, Im really stumped on what IF statement to add in order to get that last word printed!

Comment: Oh, ignore my last comment about reverse order - it's been a long day! )

Comment: Chris is correct, and I didn't spot that (though still not sure while your prog crashes).  Your IF should check: (z->val == '\n') || (z->next == NULL) - implying end of the list.  I think.  I don't have a compiler to hand to test it.

Comment: And I think in the second while() you also need to check for z->val == '\n' to stop printing the previous word again...

Comment: I've edited my original answer to include Chris' hint.  Again please note I've not checked this compiles! :)

Comment: Thanks, only problem is, it seems to be missing one the '\n' which it should contain i.e. Hello\nWorld\n.   It prints, .\nWorldHello

Comment: BTW, study this closely as this and its varients are popular interview questions.

Comment: Any advice on why Im not getting that final \n on the output, I'm  tearing my hair out!

Comment: Ah, I see.  The check in the second while loop will jump out at the \n at the end of World...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've had time to see why my first answer wouldn't work - a few little obvious things if you run the code through a debugger.  So here's a fully working version.  It could probably be optimised quite a bit, but it follows the same structure as your original code so hopefully you can follow it:

```
typedef struct L { 
    char val;
    struct L *next;
    struct L *prev;
} List;

List* insertList( char val, List *t1 ) {
    List *t = calloc(1, sizeof( List ));
    t->prev = NULL;
    t->val = val;
    t->next = t1;
    if (t1 != NULL)
        t1->prev = t;
    return t;
}

List* createList( void ) {
    List *h = NULL;
    char c;

    do {
        c =(char)getchar();
        h = insertList( c, h );
    } while (c != '.');

    return h;
}

void freeList( List *list ) {
    // free the linked list
    if (list != NULL) {
        freeList( list->next );
        free( list );
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    // create list
    List *head = createList();
    List *pos = head, *currentChar = NULL, *wordStart = NULL;

    while (pos != NULL)
    {
        // find next word
        wordStart = NULL;
        while (pos != NULL)
        {
            // gone past the beginning of a word yet?
            if ((pos->val == '\n') || (pos->next == NULL)) 
            {
                wordStart = (pos->next == NULL) ? pos : pos->prev; // note where this word starts
                pos = pos->next; // jump over \n, or go to end of list (null), for next time into this loop
                break; // jump out of this loop so we can output the word
            }
            else // not found end of word yet - on to next char
                pos = pos->next;
        }

        // have we found a word? if so, output it!
        if (wordStart != NULL)
        {
            currentChar = wordStart; // start at first char in the word
            while (currentChar != NULL)
            {
                printf( "%c", currentChar->val ); // output this char
                currentChar = currentChar->prev; // on to next char in the word
                if ((currentChar != NULL) && (currentChar->val == '\n')) 
                    break; // stop after last char of the word
            }
            // print the line-feed just before wordStart (if there is one)
            if (wordStart->next != NULL)
                printf( "%c", wordStart->next->val );
        }
        else // we've reached the end - stop
            break; // not really necessary - pos should be NULL at this point anyway
    }

    freeList( head ); // free linked list memory

    return 0;
}
```

The main change is how I output the linefeed.  I realised it's NOT the linefeed after each word you need, but the one just BEFORE it (not logical at all - I wonder if that is what the question originally intended?).  But it now outputs exactly what you require.  And I've added a function to free the linked list memory at the end too for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.c>
struct dnode{
int data;
struct dnode *prev,*next;
};
typedef struct dnode DNODE;
DNODE *first;
DNODE *last;

DNODE* createDnode(int ele){
DNODE *nnode;
nnode=(DNODE *)malloc(sizeof(DNODE));
nnode->data=ele;
nnode->next=NULL;
nnode->prev=NULL;
return nnode;
```

}

```
//Insert First

DNODE *insertFirst(int ele){
DNODE *nnode;
nnode=createDnode(ele);
if(first==NULL){ //if node is creating first time
    first=last=nnode;
    return;    
}
nnode->prev=NULL;
nnode->next=first;
first=nnode;
return first;
} 

//Insert Last

DNODE *insertLast(int ele){
DNODE *nnode;
nnode=createDnode(ele);
if(first==NULL){ //if node is creating first time
    first=last=nnode;
    return;    
}
last->next=nnode;
nnode->prev=last;
last=nnode;
return last;    
}

 //Insert Before an Element

DNODE *insertBefore(int ele,int key){
DNODE *nnode,*curr,*pre;
nnode=createDnode(ele);
if(first==NULL){ //if node is creating first time
    first=last=nnode;
    return;    
}
if(first->data==key){  // if key is found at first node
    nnode->next=first;
    first=nnode; 
    return first;   
}
curr=first;
while(curr && curr->data!=key){
    pre=curr;
    curr=curr->next;   
}   
if(!curr){   //if search not found then curr will be NULL, it's means the node is added at last
    last->next=nnode;
    nnode->prev=last;
    last=nnode;
    return last;
}
    curr->prev->next=nnode;
    nnode->prev=curr->prev;
    nnode->next=curr;
    curr->prev=nnode;
    return;
  }

 // Insert After an Element

  DNODE *insertAfter(int ele,int key){
  DNODE *nnode,*curr,*pre;
  nnode=createDnode(ele);
  if(first==NULL){ //if node is creating first time
    first=last=nnode;
    return;    
}
curr=first;
while(curr && curr->data!=key){
    //pre=curr;
    curr=curr->next;   
}   
if(!curr){   //if search not found then curr will be NULL, it's means the node        is added at last
    last->next=nnode;
    nnode->prev=last;
    last=nnode;
    return last;
}
nnode->next=curr->next;
curr->next->prev=nnode;
nnode->prev=curr;
curr->next=nnode;
return;
```

}

// Remove Function

```
int removeNode(int key){
DNODE *curr;
if(first==NULL){ //if node is creating first time
    printf("\n\nList is Empty");
    return -1;    
}
curr=first;
if(first->data==key){  //if first node has key
   first=first->next;
   first->prev=NULL;
   curr->next = NULL;
   free(curr);
   return;
}

while(curr && curr->data!=key){
    curr=curr->next;   
} 
if(!curr){   //if search not found then curr will be NULL, 
    return -1;
}

curr->prev->next=curr->next;
curr->next->prev=curr->prev;
curr->next = curr->prev = NULL;
printf("\n\n%d is Successfully Deleted: ",curr->data);
free(curr);
return;
}

void display(){
DNODE *curr;
if(first==NULL)
    printf("\n\nNothing to Display\n\n");
curr=first;
printf("\n\n\tElement in List\n\n\t");
while(curr){
    printf("%d ",curr->data);
    curr=curr->next;    
  }
 }
 main(){
int ele,ch,key;
do{
    printf("\nEnter Your Choice: \n");
    printf("1-Insert First\t2-Insert Last\n3-Insert Before\t4-Insert After\n5-Remove  \t6-Display\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch){
        case 1:
            printf("Enter Element To Insert: ");
            scanf("%d",&ele);
            insertFirst(ele);
            break;  
        case 2:
            printf("Enter Element To Insert: ");
            scanf("%d",&ele);
            insertLast(ele);
            break;
         case 3:
            printf("Enter Element To Insert: ");
            scanf("%d",&ele);
            printf("\nEnter Key: ");
            scanf("%d",&key);
            insertBefore(ele,key);
            break;  
        case 4:
            printf("Enter Element To Insert: ");
            scanf("%d",&ele);
            printf("\nEnter Key: ");
            scanf("%d",&key);
            insertAfter(ele,key);
            break; 
        case 5:
            printf("Enter Key to Delete: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d",&key);
            removeNode(key);
            break;
        case 6:
            display();
            break;
    }  
}while(ch!=7);
getch();
return 0;
```

}